# Metro bundler looks for react-native entry point in the wrong place

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

If I run `"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",` and then `react-native run-ios` the simulator starts up just fine and the bundler serves the js. However, react-native is smart and can start the metro bundler automatically if there is no server open and I run the command `react-native run-ios`. However, when it opens automatically, it writes a line saying it is looking for the JS files in `/Users/.../sc/projectDir/node_modules/react-native`. This started happening after I upgraded to `react-native 59.0`. Our pipeline relies on the automatic spawning of the bundler for integration tests. Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution.

Comment: Do you have react-native installed globally by any chance ?

Comment: @Blimeys i upgraded to 59.1 and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 59.1 solved the issue.